# Getting canvas width trouble

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Okay. So I have a canvas with an id of mainCanvas, with javascript and css on the same html page. I want to have it so that I can make things a certain width of the canvas, in javascript (Example, a red rectangle be the width and height of the canvas). So I have the canvas width set to 60% and the height set to 500px (the height isn't the problem) in css, and I have the code,

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
var context = document.getContext("2d");

var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;
```

which gets the canvas width and height. Then I have a setInterval() function with a game function that calls and update function, and a render function.

```
function game() {
    update();
    render();
}

function update() {

}

function render() {
    context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
}

setInterval(function() {
    game();
}, 1000/30);
```

So I have a rectangle that has the width variable as the width parameter, and the height variable as the height parameter.

Just so it is easier to see, here is a snippet.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style type="text/css">
  body {
   background-color: #222222;
  }
  canvas {
   background-color: #1f1f1f;
   width: 60%;
   height: 500px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="mainCanvas"></canvas>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  
  var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
  var context = document.getContext("2d");

  var width = canvas.width;
  var height = canvas.height;

  function game() {
   update();
   render();
  }

  function update() {

  }

  function render() {
   context.fillStyle = "red";
   context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
  }

  setInterval(function() {
   game();
  }, 1000/30);

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is the width and height not working? I have seen many questions on stackoverflow but those don't fix my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line:

```
var context = document.getContext("2d");
```

To:

```
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d"); // `canvas` instead of `document`

var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;
```